# run tests automatically after sources changed

Tags: c++, python, unit-testing

I use [Cxxtest](http://cxxtest.sourceforge.net/guide.html) for unit-testing my C++ code. I would like that each time I change and save my code, tests are run (simply, by `make tests`). I know that for Python there is [Nosy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nosy) that enables that. Is there some generic program that would allow this for Cxxtest or any other testing unit?

Simply, I just need running  a single command of files` change. It wouldn't be difficult to write script like that, but maybe there is some tool already : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyed that there is no ready and simple solution, i just created a simple tool: [changerun](http://code.google.com/p/changerun/) to run commands when files' change. I hope someone will find it useful : )

Comment: Forgot to add downloadable, just fixed.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use a filesystem monitoring daemon like [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to run a command (e.g. `make tests`) every time a file is changed in a directory (a so-called `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event).

Comment: icron seems perfect... but it does compile. But I will try more, thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using? On Debian or Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install incron` should work.

Comment: can you make `incron` to run not as a daemon? That is, keep running in console and output result of `make test`?

Comment: AFAIK, no, incrond must run as a daemon. However, you could write your own program using [inotify-cxx](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify-cxx&page=about&lang=en()) to monitor the directory and show the output in a terminal. Or, using incrond, you could have the output saved to a file, or mailed to you.

Comment: You could also create an incron job that executes the command `x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c "make test | less"`. This will open a new window, run `make test` piped through `less`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use TeamCity for this. It can monitor your code repository and run automated builds + unit tests when changes are detected.. Includes a decent web style interface and emailing capability to notify of build/test failures..

It can also be configured for both windows and linux builds..

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

If thats a bit heavyweight for you, then you should be able to configure your build process to run the tests for you (e.g. edit your makefile on linux), but obviously this would still mean you manually kicking off a build when you make changes (which I guess you'd probably do anyway)..